# How to find the maximum value for each key in a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary, max, defaultdict

How can I extract the maximum value for each key in a dictionary of lists?

For example

```
#Generate some sample data
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)

>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

I would like to return the following results:

```
blue 4
red 1
yellow 3
```

I have unsuccessfully tried looping over the dictionary and extracting the list values.  However, I cannot seem to find a way to extract the values and link them to the proper keys.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please note that I have addressed your comments in the post.

Comment: Somewhat vaguely - a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and concise description of the problem (error traceback or input and expected and actual output) is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for k, v in d.items():
    print k, max(v)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to keep around the list of all possible values, and just need the max, this will do it:

```
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = dict(sorted(s))
```

`d` is now:

```
{'blue': 4, 'yellow': 3, 'red': 1}
```

The `sorted(s)` will sort the tuples in ascending order, and the `dict` constructor will only reflect the final (highest) result.

Bonus: If you want the minimum values, `dict(sorted(s, reverse=True))` will give that to you:

```
{'blue': 2, 'red': 1, 'yellow': 1}
```

Comment: I believe this solution can be categorized under the “cool hacks” section.  However, I don't see how it makes the code more readable or efficient.

Comment: @5gon12eder I have mixed feelings about it too. The "sort a list of tuples" idiom is like the Schwartzian transform and a lot of other sorting tricks: powerful, useful...and yet, still a bit of a trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the results in a dictionary as well, you could use a one-liner generator expression.

```
items = {'blue': [2, 4], 'yellow': [1, 3], 'red': [1]}
maxitems = {k : max(items[k]) for k in items}
```